# Merge object with a string

Tags: arrays, string, object

I have object

```
var obj = {

"first": {

  "f": ['1','2','3'],
  "s": ['one','two','three']
 },

"second": {
  "s1": ['month', 'year'],
  "s2": ['day','color']
 }
}
```

And have a string text html

```
<div class="string">second</div>

var k = $('.string').text();
```

how can I get an object property

```
console.log(obj.k); // not work
console.log(obj.second) // work
console.log(obk[k]) // work
```

And next
i have second html code

```
<div class="string2">s1</div>
```

How to get an array of s1

```
var t = $('.string2').text();
obj[k].t //not work
obj[k].obj[t] // not work
```

Comment: How to get the array value as for example
obj[k].s1 // it's work
If I get a value on the same principle of the text
var k = $('.string').text();
var t = $('.string2').text();

obj[k].t //not work
obj[k].obj[t]// not work

Answer (score 0):

Try `obj[k]`. I guest this is what you are looking for

Actually when you type `obj.k`, It's looking for a field "k" in the object which is obviously missing. The syntax `obj[someVar]` let you retrieve the field corresponding to the value of `someVar`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx, it's work fine...
What next? how to get the array property on the same principle
obj[k].obj[s] ?
obj[k] in console.log(objects + property), if i dont know next property

Answer (score 0):

OK, find answer

```
obj[k][t] // it's work
```